# Search in Multiple Table With UNION But When ECHO saying undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using UNION to search in multiple table in our database. Number of rows are showing perfect but when i am trying to ECHO all record then showing first table data perfect but for another its giving undefined index error.

I tried lots but not getting exactly what i am missing.

```php
$query = "SELECT a, b, c, id, 'RSpage' as type FROM table1 WHERE sn LIKE '%" .$keyword . "%' OR tgs LIKE '%" .$keyword."%' 
           UNION
           SELECT d, e, f, id, 'RSblog' as type FROM tablblog WHERE keyw LIKE '%" .$keyword. "%' OR art LIKE '%" .$keyword."%' 
           UNION
           SELECT g, h, i, id, 'RStut' as type FROM tabletutor WHERE sanswer LIKE '%" .$keyword. "%' OR skeywords LIKE '%" .$keyword."%'
           UNION
           SELECT j, k, l, id, 'RSpack' as type FROM tablepack WHERE package_keywords LIKE '%" .$keyword. "%' OR short_description LIKE '%" .$keyword."%' LIMIT ".$first_pos.", ".$RESULTS_LIMIT."";

           $sql_result_query = mysqli_query($con_new,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result_query))
{

if($row["type"] == "RSpage")
{                                       
Working fine and printing all value what i want.
}

if($row["type"] == "RSblog")
{
Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\RSSeoSolution\search_new.php on line                                      
}
if($row["type"] == "RStut")
{
Notice: Undefined index: squestion in C:\xampp\htdocs\RSSeoSolution\search_new.php on line                                          }
if($row["type"] == "RSpack")
{
Notice: Undefined index: package_title in C:\xampp\htdocs\RSSeoSolution\search_new.php on line                                          }
                                        }
```

I want to show all result but its fetching row perfectly but dont why showing undefined variable.

Please guide me because its help me to make one search page from entire website.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ..... going to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column names returned from a `UNION` query are set by the first `SELECT` query, so for your subsequent queries the names are not what you expect. For example, for type `RSblog`, `title` is called `pg`, `desc` is called `sn` and `purl` is called `tgs` (`id` remains the same). The same applies to your other `SELECT`s in the `UNION`. So for `$row["type"] == "RSblog"`, use something like

```
$title = $row['pg'];
$desc = $row['sn'];
$purl = $row['tgs'];
```

And likewise for the others.

Comment: Thanks ......... we arrange value and now its working fine. Now i am able to show multiple page search at single search page. Thanks lots.